# mouse focus is locked on one window

Tags: windows-10, mouse, docker-for-windows

I am having a very weird behavior, and it is happening frequently since I installed docker desktop.
The mouse focus locks to a certain window and cannot be changed. The keyboard works perfectly, but for example, if I go to desktop by pressing `winkey+D` the desktop is shown, and I can still navigate using my keyboard, but the mouse only works in the windows it is frozen in (chrome for example), not even the taskbar can be interacted with in this state. I stopped docker from PowerShell using `Get-Process docker | Stop-Process`. And things went back to normal. Any Idea what might cause this issue?

Comment: What happens when some other window (or the Start Page) comes within that window area ? What happens when you use alt-tab to move to a window which totally covers that window ?

Comment: it just acts as if that windows doesn't exist ( on the mouse) keyboard is all fine

Comment: It will not allow the mouse to move over the Part covered by Other Window ? Or It will allow mouse to move there but mouse click on that Area still goes to Original Window ? Strange ! When Some Newer window is (Partially) Covering the Original Window , it should have lost focus.

Comment: yes exactly! I have around 5 years of IT support and having this happen to me is pretty dazzling. the mouse is allowed outside the window, just clicking on the other windows does nothing (including taskbar and desktop). even after switching focus using `alt + tab`, keyboard works but mouse still doesn't

Comment: I don't know if I should delete the question, but I have found out what the reason is, it is my external mouse. since the issue happens only when I use it (even if on another computer). the weird thing is when I unplug it, the issue doesn't go away. but if it was never plugged the issue doesn't happen at all. still curious as to how can a mouse produce such behavior

Comment: Which mouse is that ?

Comment: asus rog gx950. recalling now, I had wiped it with a damp towel a week ago. but I actually opened it and made sure all is dry. Had it for about 6 years of daily use and I would actually get the model again if I find one in my country

Comment: I ran into something similar. I tried to launch Task Manager (Ctr+Shift+Esc), but I still couldn't pull focus away from the current application (which was VS Code). All windows of that application worked fine, but no other windows accepted the mouse. I tried Ctr+Alt+Del, and the security screen DID work, and that seemed to release the mouse focus and fix everything.

Comment: @jaafarNasrallah I wouldn't delete the question, it was good to find it today when I had the same symptoms and see the steps others tried. If anyone has this again, they can try my solution (above), or add more info.